# Regular expression to pull out string - (Employee ID XXXXXXXXXXX)

Tags: c#, regex

I need to  pull out the following string from a text file using regular expression.

```
(EMPLOYEE ID 45678912345)
```

the format is always `(EMPLOYEE ID XXXXXXXXXXX)`
where X denotes a number. The Employee ID should be followed by exactly 11 numbers.

Comment: do you need brackets as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will capture all instances matching the regular expression ignoring case

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, @"(\(EMPLOYEE ID [0-9]{11}\))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    //capture employeeID
                      var employeeID = match.Value;
                }
```

Answer (score 7):

The following will capture the format you specified:

```
(\(EMPLOYEE ID [0-9]{11}\))
```

I'll leave the usage of this pattern and how to extract the capturing group as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if lookaheads an lookbehinds are supported in C# but to get that number (by a Rgex that support these) I would use a pattern like `(?<=\(EMPLOYEE ID )\d{11}(?=\))` **to get the number ONLY**.

Comment: Lookaheads and behinds are supported in the .NET regex engine. The OP didn't state a need to extract the number though. By the way, in the .NET engine, `\d` will match on any Unicode numeral (so Arabic numerals will match), this is different from using `[0-9]`.

Comment: @Oded Thanks for the information about C# Regex rules. Though, I don't think you need to stress what the OP asked. It's obvious.